# Create a data frame assigning it the name of an existing string

Tags: r

I am in a situation where it would be convenient to both access and create data frames using existing strings as names.

I can do the accessing just fine, e.g.:

```
> foo <- data.frame(test=1:2)
> mystring <- "foo"
> head(get(mystring))
  test
1    1
2    2
```

However, suppose I want to create a data frame named `bar`, given that I have `mystring <- 'bar'`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
assign(mystring,data.frame(test=1:2))
```

With `mystring <- "bar"`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure who was first so I will chose the accepted answer randomly.

Comment: @BenS. The answer which appears first is the one posted first.

Comment: @BenS. In order to see the order of answering you can refresh the page with F5 and then see which post is the first, but if you decide a random choice I agree just try to be a bit bayesian ;)

Comment: @BenS., hover over the "answered x mins ago" to get the precise timestamp ;-)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Really smart suggestion and as that credit who wha the first poster, I will remove that boring words.

Comment: well it was a close one but 16:54:57 is clearly less than 16:55:10, congrats Duck!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `assign`

```
assign(mystring, data.frame(test = 1:2))
```

---

Or with `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(list(data.frame(test = 1:2)), mystring), .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
mystring <- "bar"
```